# Typescript React Props rendering wrong items

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and have been stuck on this problem for some time. I am attempting to render an array of images for each post, think of the  instagram grid and how users are able to click through a carousel. However every time I type in new data the entire instagram Grid only renders the the last object data. I would like to be able to render profile1 post  from profile2 data and so forth. Here is my code.

```
export interface Profile {
  type?: string;
  caption: string;
  location: string | null;
  profileImage: string;
  username: string;
  postImages: Array<string>;
  comments: Array<Comment> | null;
  liked: boolean;
  likes: Array<Like> | null;
  favorited: boolean;
  datePosted: string;
  tagged: Array<Tag> | null;
  verified: boolean;
  profilePic?: string;
  posts?: number;
  followers?: number;
  following?: number;
}
```

Profile1 post

```
            <div className="post-image">
              {profile1.postImages.length > 1 && (
                <>
                  <div className="post-image-count">
                    {postIndex + 1}/{profile1.postImages.length}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="post-image-forwards"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setPostIndex(
                        postIndex === profile1.postImages.length - 1
                          ? 0
                          : postIndex + 1
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="post-image-backwards"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setPostIndex(
                        postIndex === 0
                          ? profile1.postImages.length - 1
                          : postIndex - 1
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
                  </button>
                </>
              )}
              
              {profile1.postImages.map((image: string, index: number) => (
                <img
                  className={`${postIndex === index ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
                  src={image}
                  alt={data.username}
                />
              ))}   
            </div>
```

```
<div className="post-image">
              {profile2.postImages.length > 1 && (
                <>
                  <div className="post-image-count">
                    {postIndex + 1}/{profile2.postImages.length}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="post-image-forwards"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setPostIndex(
                        postIndex === profile2.postImages.length - 1
                          ? 0
                          : postIndex + 1
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="post-image-backwards"
                    onClick={() =>
                      setPostIndex(
                        postIndex === 0
                          ? profile2.postImages.length - 1
                          : postIndex - 1
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
                  </button>
                </>
              )}
              
              {profile2.postImages.map((image: string, index: number) => (
                <img
                  className={`${postIndex === index ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
                  src={image}
                  alt={data.username}
                />
              ))}
              
            </div>
```

I've tried instantiating the interface as well as import json data and nothing seems to work out.

```
     <img
              style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
              src={profile2.postImages[1]}
              alt=""
            />
```

The first images always renders correctly for each post, but when I click through the carousel it shows the wrong images and data for the post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two blocks of code which are identical except that one uses `profile1` and the other uses `profile2`.  This is what props are for!  You want to define components for specific pieces of your UI, like `ProfileCarousel`, and then pass in the data as `props`.

It seems like the problem right now is that you have one `postIndex` state which you are using for both user profiles.  We need to keep that state separate for each profile.

You will create one reusable component `ProfileCarousel` and have two separate instances of it for the two separate profiles.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<div>
   <ProfileCarousel user={profile1}/>
   <ProfileCarousel user={profile2}/>
</div>
```

Though more realistically, you probably have a larger `UserProfile` component which renders a `ProfileCarousel` internally.  And you probably have an `array` of user data which you will iterate through using `.map`.

```
const ProfileCarousel = ({ user }: { user: Profile }) => {
    const [postIndex, setPostIndex] = useState(0);

    const images = user.postImages;
    const count = images.length;

    return (
        <div>
            {count > 1 && (
                <>
                    <div className="post-image-count">
                        {postIndex + 1}/{count}
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="post-image-forwards"
                        onClick={() =>
                            setPostIndex(
                                postIndex === count - 1
                                    ? 0
                                    : postIndex + 1
                            )
                        }
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="post-image-backwards"
                        onClick={() =>
                            setPostIndex(
                                postIndex === 0
                                    ? count - 1
                                    : postIndex - 1
                            )
                        }
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
            {images.map((image: string, index: number) => (
                <img
                    className={`${postIndex === index ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
                    src={image}
                    alt={user.username}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );

}

const UserProfile = ({ user }: { user: Profile }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>{user.username}</h2>
                <div>{user.followers} Followers</div>
                <div>{user.following} Following</div>
            </div>
            <ProfileCarousel user={user} />
        </div>
    );
}


const Feed = () => {

    const data: Profile[] = [] /* from some API call? */

    return (
        <ul>
            {data.map(user => (
                <li key={user.username}>
                    <UserProfile user={user} />
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}
```